# How to prove that $[(p→q)∧(q→r)]→(p→r)$ is a tautology without using a truth table?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

How to prove that [(p→q)∧(q→r)]→(p→r) is a tautology without using the truth table?
I did these steps but i did not know how to continue

≡ [ (¬p ∨ q )  ∧  ( q → r ) ] → ( p → r )  By conditional law

≡ [ (¬p ∨ q )  ∧  ( ¬q ∨  r ) ] → ( p → r )  By conditional law

≡ [ (¬p ∨ q )  ∧  ( ¬q ∨  r ) ] → ( ¬p ∨ r )  By conditional law

≡ ¬ [ (¬p ∨ q )  ∧  ( ¬q ∨  r ) ] ∨ ( ¬p ∨ r )  By conditional law

≡ ¬ (¬p ∨ q )  ∨ ¬( ¬q ∨  r ) ∨ ( ¬p ∨ r )  By DeMorgan’s

≡ p ∧ ¬ q  ∨ ¬( ¬q ∨  r ) ∨ ( ¬p ∨ r )  By DeMorgan’s

≡ p ∧ ¬ q  ∨ q ∧  ¬ r  ∨  ¬p ∨ r  By DeMorgan’s

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I think this question is a duplicate, check this one, I hope it answers your question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2954837/how-to-prove-that-p-to-q-land-q-to-r-to-p-to-r-is-a-tautology-wit?rq=1

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Isn't that just the Transitive Property which is an axiom?

Comment: The easiest way is to note $\to$ is equivalent to $\le$ on truth values.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the Conditional law, then the DeMorgan's law, what you got so far is correct. Next, try to apply distributive law and see what you get, or see the following:
\begin{align*}
&((\lnot p \lor q)\land(q\to r))\to(p\to r)\\
\equiv&\lnot((\lnot p \lor q)\land (\lnot q\lor r))\lor(\lnot p\lor r)\tag*{Conditional law}\\
\equiv&(p\land\lnot q)\lor(q\land\lnot r)\lor\lnot p\lor r\tag*{DeMorgan's law}\\
\equiv&(p\land\lnot q)\lor\lnot p\lor(q\land\lnot r)\lor r\tag*{Commutative law}\\
\equiv&((p\lor\lnot p)\land(\lnot q\lor\lnot p))\lor((q\lor r)\land(\lnot r\lor r))\tag*{Distributive law}\\
\equiv&(\top\land(\lnot q\lor\lnot p))\lor((q\lor r)\land\top)\tag*{Negation law}\\
\equiv&\lnot q\lor\lnot p\lor q\lor r\tag*{Identity law}\\
\equiv&q\lor\lnot q\lor\lnot p\lor r\tag*{Commutative law}\\
\equiv&\top\lor\lnot p\lor r\tag*{Negation law}\\
\equiv&\top\tag*{Domination law}
\end{align*}
Hence proved.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to show a formula is a tautology is to derive the formula from an empty set of premises using the inference rules of your given system.

So, if you're working with a natural deduction system consisting of the inference rules *Modus Ponens* (MP), *Conjunction Elimination* ($\wedge$E), and *Conditional Proof* (CP), then you can show

$\vdash [(p \to q) \wedge (q \to r)] \to (p \to r)$

is a tautology as follows...

$
\begin{array}{llll}
\{1\} & 1. & (p \to q) \wedge (q \to r) & \text{Assumption for CP} \\
\{1\} & 2. & p \to q & \text{$1$ $\wedge$E} \\
\{1\} & 3. & q \to r & \text{$1$ $\wedge$E} \\
\{4\} & 4. & p & \text{Assumption for CP} \\
\{1,4\} & 5. & q & \text{$2,4$ MP} \\
\{1,4\} & 6. & r & \text{$3,5$ MP} \\
\{1\} & 7. & p \to r & \text{$4,6$ CP} \\
\emptyset & 8. & [(p \to q) \wedge (q \to r)] \to (p \to r) & \text{$1,7$ CP} & \square \\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lnot ((\lnot p \lor q) \land (\lnot q \lor r)) \lor (\lnot p \lor r)$$

Distribution

$$\equiv\lnot (
(\lnot p \land \lnot q)
\lor
(\lnot p \land r)
\lor
(q \land r)
) \lor (\lnot p \lor r)$$

$\lnot$ DNF=CNF
$$\equiv(
(p \lor q)
\land
(p \lor \lnot r)
\land
(\lnot q \lor \lnot r)
) \lor (\lnot p \lor r)$$

Distribution

$$\equiv(
(p \land (q \lor \lnot r)
\land
(\lnot q \lor \lnot r)
) \lor (\lnot p \lor r)$$

Absorption

$$\equiv(p \land \lnot r) \lor (\lnot p \lor r)$$

$$\equiv(p \land \lnot r) \lor (\lnot p\land r) \lor (\lnot p\land \lnot r) \lor (p \land r)$$

$$\equiv \top$$